# Draw and fill a polygon from 2 lines using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, polygon, contour

I have a picture with 2 curves and multiple small lines which can be interpreted as noise.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TBwg.png)

I need to create a polygon with these curves and fill them with white like the output below :

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRt5Y.png)

I tried the following code :

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from google.colab import drive
import numpy as np

filePath = '/gdrive/My Drive/teste17.png'
image = cv2.imread(filePath)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

cv2_imshow(image)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))

c2=np.stack((coords[:,1], coords[:,0]), axis=-1)


cv2.fillPoly(image, [c2], (255, 0, 0))

cv2_imshow(image)
```

But the output was a bit different from what I wanted :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DovEt.png)

Is there a better approach using openCV ? Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please provide some code for us to see which efforts you already put into it. What have you done so far?

Comment: I edited my post with what I tried so far.

Comment: I see that you are already calculating the perimeter of every contour, why don't you use that perimeter to discard the "small lines which can be interpreted as noise"? With the contours of only the big lines should be easier to do what you want.